# Illegal string offset in Fat Free Framework template

Tags: fat-free-framework

I fetch a result in Fat Free Framework with this:

```
$product = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'products');    
$product->load(array('productId=:ID',':ID'=>$productId));
```

Then I walk through $product using the dry() method and do some calculations to some of it's fields. I want to make the re-calculated content of the **$product** available in my template, so I do:

```
$f3->set('product_contents', $product);
```

Now, when in my template I do:

```
<repeat group ="{{@product_contents}}" value="{{@item}}">
   <p>{{@item.productName}}</p>
</repeat>
```

I get this error:

```
Internal Server Error
Illegal string offset 'productName'
```

I discovered that my **{{@product_contents}}** is a mapper object and not an array, hence the error.

The question is:
how can I still use the contents of $product in my template in repeat groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cast()](http://fatfreeframework.com/sql-mapper#cast) method is there to cast a mapper object to an array:

```
$f3->set('product_contents', $product->cast());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just load the result into a variable
`$output = $product->load(array('productId=:ID',':ID'=>$productId));`
`$f3->set('product_contents', $output);`